# EntityFramework Core Loadbalanced

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, microservices

I know this is a pretty general question, but please bear with me:

I just tripped over the entityframework cache aka ChangeTracker.

What we have is a small microservice using net core with entity core.  This microservice is loadbalanced (RoundRobin) behind an IIS (so far nothing to incommon I would guess).  Lets call them Instance1 and Instance2.

Now what happens:

I have one entry in the db, for example (Represented as JSON here for simplicity):

`{ Name: "Test", FirstName: "T." }`

Now I load this into a form (answer from Instance1) and modify the FirstName to Thomas and save it via a PUT, which is done by Instance2.  Now I do another request to get that entry.  This request is answered by Instance1, which will load this from cache (since the changetracker says it is unchanged).  And thus I get

`{Name: "Test", FirstName: "T."}`

There seems to be many people having problems with the change tracker and one common answer is to rebuild the dbcontext with every request, which to me seems utterly wrong, because this is a very "expensive" operation.

Also I noticed that the inserting of new data gets slower and slower over time, because the change tracker is filling up, so I would have to recycle the microservice every once and a while.

So my question is:
How can I get around this Problem without reinitialising the dbcontext with every request?
I also found some answers that allow to disable the caching, but only for a single db operation, which means I would have to add this option to every DB operation, which to me feels almost as wrong as reinitialising the db context with every request.
What did I overlook, there has to be a simple solution!

Comment: I think you should not be thinking of the change tracker as a cache mechanism. It is used exactly for tracking changes per db context. Use new db context per request which i think is the right choice. If you need cache don't use the db context for this purpose, use memcache or the buildin for .net System.Runtime.Caching for example. Of course you will still need to sync the cache with the database but your db context won't get bloated with tracked (not synced) entities. Btw creating new db context is very cheap/light operation because there is a connection pool behind it.

Comment: Yea, you seriously messed it up. DbContext has to be scoped (one instance per request) which is default behaviour. You must have it as singleton somewhere. Better use Redis or something similar for distributing caching

Comment: Well I inject the db context into my repository.  My repo gets injected into the controller, but as a singleton, so it seems that this is my mistake.  If I make my repository a Scoped then it should be created with every request, also then injecting a new db context into it?
I will try this tomorrow, thank you for your ansers!

Comment: @vasiloreshenski `creating new db context is very cheap/light operation because there is a connection pool behind it.` are you sure that is true?

Comment: @PWFraley yes setting your repository as scoped should fix this, assuming you are also injecting your dbcontext as scoped as well - which is the default for `AddDbContext<TContext>()`

Comment: @Mardoxx Yes, check out here for more info https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8xx3tyca.aspx if you are interested. It is about ado.net but EF use it internally.

Comment: @vasiloreshenski is that not within the same scope though, as soon as the object is destroyed surely the connection pool is destroyed too?

Comment: @Mardoxx No the connection pool is not disposed by the db context or controlled by EF. Check this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/orm-9780596520281-01-16.aspx. It states the following: 'Because connection pooling is controlled by the database provider, the Entity Framework does not explicitly impact or interact with how connection pooling works. Instead, it relies on the provider's connection pooling'.

Comment: @vasiloreshenski ahh wow thanks did not know that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that your any injected classes which make use of Entity Framework have the same lifetime as your `DbContext`. Default would be `Scoped`. Easy mistake to make, don't sweat!

See this section and the big red warning near the bottom: 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection#registering-your-own-services